# ¿Cómo cargar el fichero policy sin mandar parámetros a la JVM?

Tags: java

Tengo un Dynamic web project, concretamente estoy trabajando con un applet que a su vez llama a otros Jars.
Localmente, en el apartado Run configurations de Eclipse, puedo decirle a la vm que carge el fichero mediante los argumentos:

```
-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/path/to/other.policy
```

O también puedo modificar el fichero java.policy que Java tiene por defecto en la carpeta:

```
/lib/security/java.policy
```

Entonces

¿Cómo lo hago si la app va a estar en maquinas de usuarios o en servidores de terceros? No puedo modificar el fichero java.policy de cada usuario o el del servidor de terceros ni enviar parámetros a la vm.

¿Cómo hacer que la vm cargue el policy de cada Jar? No todos los jars tienen los mismos permisos de acceso a los recursos.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo lo hago si la app va a estar en maquinas de usuarios o en servidores de terceros? No puedo modificar el fichero java.policy de cada usuario o el del servidor de terceros ni enviar parámetros a la vm.

No puedes porque sería un grave fallo de seguridad: Si un applet pudiese usar un fichero policy que estuviese, por ejemplo, en una URL externa a la máquina del cliente, todo el sistema estaría comprometido.

Si quieres que el sistema confíe en tu Applet (algo que se considera obsoleto hoy día), deberá estar *firmada*, con lo que podrías pedir permisos al usuario para acceder a los recursos del sistema (por ejemplo, a ficheros).